# Linux shell list file what's the difference bewteen tmp/**/* and tmp/*

Tags: shell, unix

I encounter one problem about the file system in the shell.
what's difference between `tmp/**/*` and `tmp/*`?
I make the experiment in my system,
have this directory dir2

```
dir2
     -->dir1
         -->xx2
     -->ff.txt
```

and I run `ls dir2/*`:

```
dir2/ff.txt

 dir2/dir1:
 xx2
```

then I run `ls dir2/**/*`:

```
dir2/dir1/xx2
```

So it means the `**` is to ignore this directory(like ignore the dir1),
Can some one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a formatting issue in the question test, but I'll answer based on the question title and examples.

There shouldn't be any difference between a single and double asterisk at any single level of the path. Either expression matches any name, except for hidden ones which start with a dot (this can be changed by shell options). So:

- `tmp/**/*` (equivalent to `tmp/*/*`) is expanded to all names which are nested two levels deep in `tmp`. The first asterisk expands only to directories and not files at the first level because it's followed by a slash.
- `tmp/*` expands to anything nested one level deep inside `tmp`.

To this comes the fact that `ls` will list contents of directory if a directory is given on its command line. This can be overridden by adding `-d` option to `ls`.

Comment: So you means the tmp/*/* just list two levels deep in the tmp?
But I have a issue about this
I see the book (Ruby-on-rails-3-tutorial), and the author show the .gitignore file:
.bundle
lpg/*.log
tmp/**/*
tmp/*
and so on....
So if the tmp/* include the tmp/**/*, why he add the tmp/**/*?
And I test the tmp/**/* and tmp/*/*, the result is the same.

Comment: In some shells etc, `**` expands to an arbitrarily deep subdirectory structure. So `/**/foo` matches `/foo`, `/tmp/foo`, `/tmp/bar/foo`, `/tmp/bar/quux/foo`, etc.

Comment: @tripleee Good point, I'm so used to bash/sh I almost forget there are other shells around. The example in OP is consistent with bash's behavior, though, since there are only two levels of nesting, so no difference can be seen between the two possible behaviors of `**`.

Comment: Thanks tripleee and Michal, I really know the difference between ** and *.